# R при чтении json дублирует поля

Tags: json, r

Я только начал изучать r и сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть json файл:

```
[
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Левенць Наталія Іванівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель математики",
   "Years_practice": 46,
   "Position": "директор",
   "Category": "вища"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Кулянда Оксана Сергіївна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель української мови та літератури",
   "Years_practice": 29,
   "Position": "заступник директора з навчально-виховної роботи",
   "Category": "вища"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Бакалець Ганна Миронівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель з основ здоров'я",
   "Years_practice": 2,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "спеціаліст"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Бабіна Марія Олександрівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель української мови та літератури, зарубіжної літератури, російської мови та літератури",
   "Years_practice": 7,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "спеціаліст"
 }
]
```

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
library(RJSONIO)
ped4<-fromJSON(file = "e:/DEP/Gol/Ped4.json")
json_ped4<-as.data.frame(ped4)
```

Результат:

```
> names(json_ped4)
  [1] "Ua_edr"            "Education_name"    "Short_name"        "Teacher_Name"      "Sex"              
  [6] "Status"            "Years_practice"    "Position"          "Category"          "Ua_edr.1"         
 [11] "Education_name.1"  "Short_name.1"      "Teacher_Name.1"    "Sex.1"             "Status.1"         
 [16] "Years_practice.1"  "Position.1"        "Category.1"        "Ua_edr.2"          "Education_name.2" 
 [21] "Short_name.2"      "Teacher_Name.2"    "Sex.2"             "Status.2"          "Years_practice.2" 
 [26] "Position.2"        "Category.2"        "Ua_edr.3"          "Education_name.3"  "Short_name.3"     
 [31] "Teacher_Name.3"    "Sex.3"             "Status.3"          "Years_practice.3"  "Position.3"       
 [36] "Category.3"        "Ua_edr.4"          "Education_name.4"  "Short_name.4"      "Teacher_Name.4"
```

Тоесть все поля дублируются по колличеству блоков:

Ua_edr, Ua_edr1, ..... Ua_edr4

Возможно ли зделать структуру как c#.

Помогите зделать, что бы все данные были в одном поле (например как в файле .csv), а не так:

```
View(ped4)
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJMWd.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz3UU.png
```

Comment: Приведите пример желаемого результата, т.к. не понятно, что значит «Возможно ли зделать структуру как c#».

Comment: Библиотека ```jsonlite``` хорошо подходит для парсинга данных из файла ```.json```. Для лучшего понимания работы этой библиотеки советую почитать её виньетки на [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пакет `jsonlite`. Приведённый фрагмент парсится в `data.frame`, который потом можно сохранить в CSV:

```r
> str(jsonlite::fromJSON("/tmp/test.json"))
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Ua_edr        : int  14040061 14040061 14040061 14040061
 $ Education_name: chr  "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4"
 $ Short_name    : chr  "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4" "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4"
 $ Teacher_Name  : chr  "Левенць Наталія Іванівна" "Кулянда Оксана Сергіївна" "Бакалець Ганна Миронівна" "Бабіна Марія Олександрівна"
 $ Sex           : chr  "жін." "жін." "жін." "жін."
 $ Status        : chr  "вчитель математики" "вчитель української мови та літератури" "вчитель з основ здоров'я" "вчитель української мови та літератури, зарубіжної літератури, російської мови та літератури"
 $ Years_practice: int  46 29 2 7
 $ Position      : chr  "директор" "заступник директора з навчально-виховної роботи" "вчитель" "вчитель"
 $ Category      : chr  "вища" "вища" "спеціаліст" "спеціаліст"
```

Comment: Спасибо. С пакетом jsonlite всё работает!! Может подскажете где можно почитать об парсинге сложных json (когда в одном поле "материнской" json записано ещё несколько полей). Как то так.

Comment: Например, вот это: https://habr.com/ru/post/448950/